# Julia: parallel loops involving a function that calls another function

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have two files

`test_file.jl`

```
using Distributed

function inner_function(v)
    v_2 = 2 * v
    return v_2
end

function loop(N, v)
@sync @distributed for i in 1:N
    v_3 = inner_function(v)
    v_3[1] = i
    println(i)
    println(v_3)
end
end
```

`test_file_call.jl`

```
@everywhere include("test_file.jl")
v = [1 2 3 4]
loop(100,v_2)
```

When I run `julia -p 2 test_file_call.jl`, I get an error saying that

> ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: v_2 not defined

I'm not sure why. `v_2` is a variable created in a function and I've already used `@everywhere include("test_file.jl")` so Julia shouldn't say that the variable is undefined. Can I get a hint? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `v_2` in `loop(100, v_2)` call, so Julia looks for `v_2` in global scope and does not find it there. Probably you wanted to write `loop(100, v)` as you define `v`.